# Off-topic flag declined for "Recommend a resource" question

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22950030/4) question as off-topic because it is, basically, "Recommend a Python module that can do X"

> Does a module exist for Python for random access of indexed gzipped
>   files (and indexing of gzipped files)?

If that's not asking to recommend an off-site resource, I don't know what is.

What gives? I ask, because this is bringing me dangerously close to a flag ban after having two NAA flags declined last week (those answers are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37937915/3714940) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37938770/3714940), FWIW)

Comment: At what time did you flag? If it was around [this close review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/12846220) that could be related.

Comment: Hi @rene, thank you.Yes, it was at 07:15:30Z, according to the timestamp, so before this review. How on earth did three separate people think that this should stay open??

Comment: Y'all need to move along.  This particular question is causing no harm to the site, especially with the resource request removed.

Comment: I apologize. I'm beginning to regret invoking the meta effect particularly as the question does actually have a useful self-answer.

Comment: Ah. I see it has been re-opened.

Comment: Is this essentially a duplicate of [Flag declined after an edit. How can we fix this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116764/flag-declined-after-an-edit-how-can-we-fix-this). There is also a related [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107397/indicate-that-a-post-has-been-edited-since-being-flagged)

Comment: @J.J.Hakala actually, the flag was declined before the edit. The edit happened well after SiHa asked this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[As said before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/213575):

> ### Is closure the end of the road for a question?
>
> Definitely not. Closed questions can and should be edited to improve them and **address the reasons why they were closed in the first place.** Once this is done you might need to either flag the question for moderator attention or raise a meta question to bring it to everyone's attention so it can get the necessary views that might translate into reopen votes.

The question was definitively worded as a recommendation question, and at least one user took [that as face value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38092525/792066). You can edit it if you can reword it to extract the problem the user is facing (through be aware that "reviewers" may reject your edit, even if that signifies salvaging a question) or vote to close it. I'm unsure why the reviewers did what they did (didn't edit the question either), but at the time, your flag was valid and warranted.